# Compare difference between GETDATE() and Datetime2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I want to check the amount of hours difference there is between current time (`GETDATE()`) and `StartTime`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    CheckedOut, GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime, StartTime
FROM 
    TimeRecordModels 
WHERE 
    CheckedOut = 0;
```

Also I want to make the bool `CheckedOut` true if the difference is higher than 15 hours and then set column name `EndTime` to `GETDATE()`

Comment: Go to BOL and look up DATEDIFF.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, GETDATE())`

Comment: Also be more specific on your conditions.  Depending on how you look at it, the difference between 1:00 and 2:59 in hours could either be equal to or greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
SELECT CheckedOut, GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime, StartTime,
       DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, GETDATE()) AS HoursDifference
    FROM TimeRecordModels 
    WHERE CheckedOut = 0;
```

To accomplish your update:

```
UPDATE TimeRecordModels
    SET CheckedOut = 1,
        EndTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, GETDATE()) > 15
        AND CheckedOut = 0;
```